# Java8 appendPattern vs pattern defined by appendValue methods produces different result

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I have the pattern "ddMMyy" in my code I have specified it using the appendValue methods:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
                    .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
                    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2)
                    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("100199", dateTimeFormatter));
```

However this produces "0099" for year:

> 0099-01-10

If I change that to using the appendPattern like that:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendPattern("ddMMyy")
                    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("100199", dateTimeFormatter));
```

I have the correct result for year "2099" with century in it.

> 2099-01-10

The code seems equivalent for me why isn't it producing the same result? Why is the century missing in the first case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `appendValue` takes the year as it is being passed without further manipulation - in your case 99.

If you want to start from a "base year", say 2000, and add the value to that base year (to get 2099) you can use `appendValueReduced` instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 2, 2, LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1))
        .toFormatter();
```

When you use the `yy` pattern, you get that behaviour by default as detailed in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> **Year**: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two digits. For parsing, this will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive. [...]